# How to convert .mat file into netcdf file (.nc) using Python?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, python-xarray

I have different .mat files such as
`file_1.mat, file_2.mat, ..., file_n.mat` with `var1, var2, ..., varn` in each `file_x.mat`. The variables do have the same name between the different files but not the same shape. However, their shape is equal within the same `.mat` file.

I usually load them in Python with `spicy.io.loadmat()` ([documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)) but I want to convert them to netcdf to use them later with xarray and accelerate my computation time. I was thinking some of you must have done this before me, jumping from Matlab to Python.

Is there any built-in function to do that ? Since my variables have the same name, I think something can be created with not too much difficulties, except we need to access the different dimensions of my variables depending on the file.

Thanks !!

Comment: Unfortunately this is pretty much doomed to be a gross manual process. Because .mat files only store arrays without labeled dimensions or coordinates, this is necessarily a data curation process on your end that requires naming each dim and binding each arrays dims to specific coordinates. The most you can automate it iirc is to associate coordinates and arrays based on dimension length, but if you have multiple coordinates of the same length there’s no way to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

I have something and I think it is a first step from what I want to do. It is really specific to my request. The thing is, you need to understand what is in your matfile, before constructing the appropriate dimensions.

```
def convert_to_nc(num:int, step:str, nn:str):
# nn correspond to a path to access the .mat file and where I want to save my new netcdf file
if nn == 'CANYONB':
    chemin = 'xx/{}.mat'.format(num)
elif nn == 'ESPER':
    chemin = 'xy/{}.mat'.format(num)
elif nn == 'CONTENT':
    chemin = 'yy/{}.mat'.format(num)
matfile = sc.io.loadmat(chemin)   
# CONDITION to choose the variables we want from the .mat file
var = [i for i in matfile[step].dtype.names if 'ci' not in i]
#var = [i for i in var if 'sigma' not in i]
#var = [i for i in var if 'raw' not in i]
#var = [i for i in var if 'cy' not in i]
print(var)
# I will open another netcdf file to look for the corresponding dimensions
ds = xr.open_dataset('my_alreadygoodnetcdf_{}.nc'.format(num))
ds_exit = xr.Dataset()
for name in range(len(var)):
    ds_exit[var[name]] = (("PRES_INTERPOLATED", "N_PROF"), matfile[step][var[name]][0][0])
ds_exit = ds_exit.assign_coords(TIME=("N_PROF", ds['TIME'].values)).assign_coords(LATITUDE=("N_PROF", ds['LATITUDE'].values)).assign_coords(LONGITUDE=("N_PROF", ds['LONGITUDE'].values)).assign_coords(N_PROF=("N_PROF", ds['N_PROF'].values)).assign_coords(PRES_INTERPOLATED=("PRES_INTERPOLATED", ds['PRES_INTERPOLATED'].values))
if nn == 'CANYONB':
    save_path = 'xx/{}.nc'.format(num)
elif nn == 'ESPER':
    save_path = 'xy/{}.nc'.format(num)
elif nn =='CONTENT':
    save_path = 'yy/{}.nc'.format(num)

ds_exit.to_netcdf(save_path)
return ds_exit
```

## RUN

```
convert_to_nc(1901212, 'out', 'CONTENT')
```